# Pandas: Create monthly subtotals of unpaid invoices

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df:

Index   AMOUNT_INVOICED  INVOICED_DATE    CLOSED_DATE
0         1443.62          2019-08-01        2019-09-04
1         3585.78          2019-08-03        2019-09-04
2         68276.25         2019-08-05        2019-09-04
3         19673.84         2019-09-10        2019-11-06
4         9119.40          2019-09-11        2019-10-07
...
700       9976.25          2021-09-01        2021-10-04
701       7273.84          2021-09-01        2021-11-14
702       3129.40          2021-10-04        2021-11-23
```

Each row represents an invoice that has already been paid, the DF includes data with invoiced dates spanning from 2019-01 to today.

I'm trying to do some reporting on a monthly basis to identify how much $ was outstanding at the end of every month.

I've set up an output df that shows every month since the first invoice date, and a place to store the sum of outstanding AR for the month, it currently looks like this:

```
                    Total Outstanding AR  
Month                                              
2019-08                     0
2019-09                     0 
2019-10                     0  
...
2021-09                     0  
2021-10                     0
```

Ultimately I would like the output to look something like this:

```
                    Total Outstanding AR  
Month                                                                        
2019-08                     73,305.65 
2019-09                     28,793.24  
2019-10                     19673.84  
...
2021-09                     17,250.09  
2021-10                     10,403.24
```

Total Outstanding AR would come from summing the amount invoiced for each month where the invoice has not been closed.

For example, in 2019-08 we sum the amount invoiced for the fist three invoices, 1443.62 + 3585.78 + 68276.25 = 73,305.65, since these three invoices were left unpaid at the end of  august.  This logic would continue until the invoice is paid, but the invoice does not contribute to the outstanding AR for the month it is paid.

Can someone help me figure out the best way to go about creating my desired output?

THANK YOU!

Comment: In words, this is "sum of all invoices where invoiced_date is prior to month end" minus "sum of all invoices where closed_date is prior to month end".  Should be easy.

Comment: @timRoberts thanks for your input, can you help me create a for loop to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you ask.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'AMOUNT_INVOICED': [ 1443.62, 3585.78, 68276.25, 19673.84,
        9119.40, 9976.25, 7273.84, 3129.40 ],
    'INVOICED_DATE': [ '2019-08-01', '2019-08-03', '2019-08-05',
        '2019-09-10', '2019-09-11', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-01',
        '2021-10-04' ],
    'CLOSED_DATE': [ '2019-09-04', '2019-09-04', '2019-09-04',
         '2019-11-06', '2019-10-07', '2021-10-04', '2021-11-14',
         '2021-11-23' ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dates = []
amounts = []
for year in range(2019,2022):
    for month in range(12):
        magic = '%04d-%02d-01' % (year,month+1)
        s1 = df[df['INVOICED_DATE'] < magic]['AMOUNT_INVOICED'].sum()
        s2 = df[df['CLOSED_DATE'] < magic]['AMOUNT_INVOICED'].sum()
        print("%s %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f" % (magic, s1,s2,s1-s2))
        dates.append( magic[:7] )
        amounts.append( s1-s2 )

newdf = pd.DataFrame(amounts, index=dates, columns=['Total Outstanding AR'])
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-02-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-03-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-04-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-05-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-06-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-07-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-08-01       0.00       0.00       0.00
2019-09-01   73305.65       0.00   73305.65
2019-10-01  102098.89   73305.65   28793.24
2019-11-01  102098.89   82425.05   19673.84
2019-12-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-01-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-02-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-03-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-04-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-05-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-06-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-07-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-08-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-09-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-10-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-11-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2020-12-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-01-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-02-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-03-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-04-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-05-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-06-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-07-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-08-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-09-01  102098.89  102098.89       0.00
2021-10-01  119348.98  102098.89   17250.09
2021-11-01  122478.38  112075.14   10403.24
2021-12-01  122478.38  122478.38       0.00
         Total Outstanding AR
2019-01                  0.00
2019-02                  0.00
2019-03                  0.00
2019-04                  0.00
2019-05                  0.00
2019-06                  0.00
2019-07                  0.00
2019-08                  0.00
2019-09              73305.65
2019-10              28793.24
2019-11              19673.84
2019-12                  0.00
2020-01                  0.00
2020-02                  0.00
2020-03                  0.00
2020-04                  0.00
2020-05                  0.00
2020-06                  0.00
2020-07                  0.00
2020-08                  0.00
2020-09                  0.00
2020-10                  0.00
2020-11                  0.00
2020-12                  0.00
2021-01                  0.00
2021-02                  0.00
2021-03                  0.00
2021-04                  0.00
2021-05                  0.00
2021-06                  0.00
2021-07                  0.00
2021-08                  0.00
2021-09                  0.00
2021-10              17250.09
2021-11              10403.24
2021-12                  0.00
```

Comment: As with all `pandas` sequences, there's probably a way to do those running sums in one or two function calls without a loop.  I'm sure someone will pipe up.

Comment: this is helpful, but it appears to only be working for the first month. the later months have a higher value than they should. once the invoice is closed, it should be excluded from the following months

Comment: Oops, typo.  I'll fix.  You can see that the far right column was right, I was just saving the wrong column to the df.